# Disable Warnings when executing python code from C# with process class

Tags: python, c#, .net, process

I'm running a sample Python script through the command prompt:

```py
import warnings
print('Hello, world!')
warnings.warn('Geeks 4 Geeks !')
```

Executing script file with warnings:

```
python first_script.py Hello World!
```

Executing script file without warnings:

```
python -W "ignore" first_script.py Hello World!
```

The python script file mentioned above runs as expected from the command prompt.

Now, I am executing python code from C# with process class

```cs
string python = @"C:\\Python27\python.exe";
string myPythonApp = @"C:\\Dropbox\scripts\loadbuild\sum.py";
int x = 2;
int y = 5;

ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(python);

myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp + " " + x + " " + y;
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
myProcess.Start();
StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
string myString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += Process_ErrorDataReceived;
myProcess.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;
myProcess.WaitForExit();
myProcess.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Value received from script: " + myString);
Console.ReadLine();
```

How can we decide whether to allow or ignore warnings in this case?

The strategy I'm attempting is:

```cs
string python = @"C:\\Python27\python.exe";
string myPythonApp = @" - W 'ignore' C:\\Dropbox\scripts\loadbuild\sum.py";
```

Please share your thoughts on whether this is the right course of action.

**Update:**

When there is a warning on the script file with the following code, I am getting an exception:

```
string python = @"C:\\Python27\python.exe";
string myPythonApp = @"C:\\Dropbox\scripts\loadbuild\sum.py";
```

Exception is: "warnings.warn('Geeks 4 Geeks !')"

The following code works very well to ignore the warnings:

```
string python = @"C:\\Python27\python.exe";
string myPythonApp = @" - W 'ignore' C:\\Dropbox\scripts\loadbuild\sum.py";
```

Is there any way to display python warnings via csharp process?

Comment: Using the cmd line args sounds reasonble. And in any case you should try it and if your attempt fails give us all the details for the failure.

Comment: @wohlstad: The warnings ignore code is working fine. But When I want to display the warnings, I am getting exception. Is there any way to display python warnings via csharp process?

Comment: I can't reproduce with python 3.9.5. I am not that familiar with Python 2.x, you might consider to upgrade it.

Comment: I mean when using csharp process, the warning is logged as error in process.ErrorDataReceived event

Comment: I don't see any mention of `ErrorDataReceived` in your code above. Please post a [mre].

Comment: I have updated the code, thanks